# how send the size of an array as parameters through a function in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I work with **Xcode**, but now I want to learn and use **Visual Studio C++** and my first challenge is to send and array through a function and its size as parameters, how can I accomplish this?

```
void Llena2(int R, int C, int (*XY)[C]); //in xcode

void Llena2(int R, int C, int (*XY)[C]); //error C2057: expected constant expression
                              //error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

Is it possible to do some similar to xcode? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling with C99 standard in XCode?

Comment: As a side note, the XCode version is not proper C++.

Comment: @Claudio I have a real problem 'cause I've been reading about how to send the content of an array of characters (pointers type char) to another array of characters and until now I have no idea how to accomplish this in C++. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You should use std::vector in this case.

**Edit:**

According to [Incompatibilities Between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm),
this feature: `void test(int R, int C, int (*XY)[R][C])` (VLA) is only valid in C99 but not in C++.

> C99 also provides new declaration syntax for function parameters of
> VLA types, allowing a variable identifier or a '*' to occur within the
> brackets of an array function parameter declaration in place of a
> constant integer size expression.
>
> ...
>
> C++ does not support VLAs.

Xcode defaults to use C99, so it is valid in Xcode.

Comment: @Naruil, I need to sorting the array of characters *Name[] = {"Al","Fe","Zr"}; I mean, at the end this array of characters must change into this {"Fe", "Zr","Al"}, how can I do that in C++? Thanks in advance

Comment: The order in the result seems werid. It is not in ascending order or descending order. Can you explain more about your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a new array in your function.
An Array is (almost) a pointer. Therefore you can write:

```
void Llena2(int R, int C, int *XY);
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I forgot to mention that is an 2D array, that's why I send in xcode R and C

Comment: This is correct. Your error is in this part:

     int(*XY)[C]

You cannot pass the array like this, because C++ passes arrays by reference and doesn't take the array as an argument. You can, as pointed out, basically treat the array like a pointer, where

     *XY

is a pointer that points to the first element of the array. If the size of the array is known to be C, you could also pass

    int C

But if the size is unknown at compile time, I would suggest, as the above user has, to use a vector instead.

Comment: @Hypatia
You can do that by passing an array of pointers. It is described here pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Anyways, vectors have improved a lot in C++11, and they are a lot easier to use. Try to use them instead.

Comment: @ComicSansMS
Yea, that was before I knew it was a multi-dimensional array. I'm deleting it now.

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising that XCode allows this.

Is `C` constant? If so, you can turn the `C` paramter into a non-type template parameter:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t C>
void Llena2(int R, int XY[][C]);
```

The compiler will automatically infer `C` at compile-time this way, but this only works with the outermost dimension.

Comment: C is not a constant, is the result of an equation and I take it as the size of the Column of the array

Comment: My real problem is that I translated an equations program (in MathLab) to C and now my tutor suggested me to translate the same program (in ANSI C) to a Visual Studio C++ because will be necessary to create a graphic interface, so now I really need to learn the best I can C++. Thank you so much for your help, means a lot to me